# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString weird behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can you someone please explain me this behaviour of ParseQueryString:

```
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("/Site/controller/Index?date=now");
var obj = qs["date"]; //qs["date"] is   null
```

Why qs["date"] is null? What do I miss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you probably know, [ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) expects just the query string part of a `URL`, If you have the `URL` you can use this code:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/Site/controller/Index?date=now");
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("date");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass onlly the query string not the whole URL:

```
 var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("date=now");
```